# How to retrieve data from a Firebase database and store it in a ListArray<Class>? - Kotlin

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am facing some problems in retrieving data from my Firebase DB...
Here is my simple code

```
class Match (val teamOne: String, val teamTwo: String, val betType: String)


private var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
private var myRef = database.getReference()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    myRef.child("matches").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
            val matches = snapshot!!.children
            matches.forEach(){
                println(it.value.toString())
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
        }
    })
}
```

This is what I get from the DB:

I/System.out: {bet=GG, team1=Juventus, team2=Real Madrid}

I/System.out: {bet=Over 2.5, team1=Napoli, team2=Roma}

I/System.out: {bet=2, team1=Inter, team2=Milan}

I/System.out: {bet=X, team1=Atalanta, team2=Lazio}

I/System.out: {bet=X, team1=Crotone, team2=Spezia}

My question is: how to create now a `ListArray<Match>`?

Thanks to everybody!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are still wondering and don't want to use another database, there are two ways I achieve this:

```
val mapper = object : GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Match>>() {}
val list = arrayListOf<Match>()
val map = snapshot.getValue(mapper)
map?.forEach {
    list.add(it.value)
}
```

Or:

```
val list = MutableList<Match> = mutableListOf()
snapshot.children.mapNotNullTo(list) {
    it.getValue<Match>(Match::class.java)
}
```

***Disclaimer:*** the `Match` class might have to be a `data class`